# Previous and Next Scrolling to next post

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, each

I've been struggling with this all day.. I've got a couple of posts, each have a next and previous button. The idea is for each post and its next and previous buttons, to scroll the window to the next post or previous post. I have tried using the `each()` function and unfortunately, its tricky to get working.

This is the jQuery so far:

```
    var scrollTo = function(element) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: element.offset().top
        }, 100);
    }

function prev_next_scrolling() {
        var articles = $("article.post"),
            counter = 0;

        articles.each( function() {

            var articles = $(this);
            $('.next-btn', articles).click( function() {
                scrollTo($('article.post').eq(counter + 1));
            });

            $('.prev-btn', articles).click( function() {
                scrollTo($('article.post').eq(counter - 1));
            });
            counter++;

        });
    }
    prev_next_scrolling();
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<article class="post">
    <h2>Post Title</h2>
    <p>Post description</p>

    <a href="#" class="prev-btn">Previous</a>
    <a href="#" class="next-btn">Next</a>    
</article>
```

Here is the jsfiddle link for you guys to have a looksie!

http://jsfiddle.net/casacoda/2zM3Q/

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the fiddle to address all your concerns in the comments

[Updated Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zM3Q/6/)

I got it working without all your each code, just navigating the dom.

Let me know if you have questions about the Fiddle provided. Basically this takes advantage of your current structure being known, it finds the next ARTICLE using `parent().next()` and then finds that ARTICLEs h2.  It then uses the H2s vertical offset position to scroll to it.  Same for previous links but using `parent().prev()`

```
$(document).on('click', '.next-btn', function(){
   // find the next anchor
   var nextAnchor = $(this).closest('article').next().find('h2')
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: nextAnchor.offset().top},'slow');
});



$(document).on('click', '.prev-btn', function(){
   // find the previous anchor
   var prevAnchor = $(this).closest('article').prev().find('h2')
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: prevAnchor.offset().top},'slow');
});
```

One thing to note, if the H2 in question is already visible on the screen it will not scroll UP to anything, only if its off screen will it scroll UP to it.  Scroll down will always move the screen if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! One little thing, I made the html as simple as possible in the example, but the anchor is very nested in the article post. Is there an easier solution to find the next article without using the parent(), otherwise I'm going to be doing a lot of parent().parent().parent().. if you get me?

Thank you very much for the help so far, really appreciate it!

Comment: Absolutely just use .parent ('article')

Comment: Or is it .closest? I'll try shortly

Comment: I'm guessing u meant to post your last comment on here, not sure. You just use $(document).on('click', '.prev-btn', function(){ instead of how I had it originally

Comment: i have updated the FIDDLE to address all your concerns in the comments

Comment: Thank you very much bud, really appreciate it!

Comment: Hey, unfortunately, that didn't work entirely. What happens now is it skips the closest article, but goes to the next article and then the other dynamically added posts don't work either? Any reason as to why? thanks again!

Comment: On another note, what I've done is call the same function again, so when they click next button, `the prev_next_scrolling()` function gets called again. That seemed to work, but it seems a bit laggy and choppy at times?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `counter` is defined in the scope of `prev_next_scrolling()`, so all the functions run by the `each()` method will use the very same instance of the variable. Each time you increase `counter`, that will happen for *all* places where it has been used.

You can fix that by introducing a variable local to the function that handles a specific element -- or actually, you don't have to because jQuery already gives you exacly that as an optional parameter in the `each()` callable. See http://api.jquery.com/each/

So here's the correct code (http://jsfiddle.net/2zM3Q/3/):

```
var scrollTo = function(element) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: element.offset().top
    }, 100);
}

function prev_next_scrolling() {
    var articles = $("article.post"),
        counter = 0;

    articles.each( function(index) {

        var articles = $(this);
        $('.next-btn', articles).click( function() {
            scrollTo($('article.post').eq(index + 1));
        });

        $('.prev-btn', articles).click( function() {
            scrollTo($('article.post').eq(index - 1));
        });
        counter++;

    });
}
prev_next_scrolling();
```

There are still some problems: It doesn't check whether it already is the first/last post and if it's already at the end of the page it obviously won't scroll any further, creating the illusion of a "broken" link (because nothing seems to be happening after clicking it.)

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help, you've been amazing! One last little thing, I know I'm being cheeky. I have infinite scrolling on this website and only the first 3 post show up normally in the dom, but when scrolling further it fetches some more posts and then gets dynamically added after the last article post, how do I bind the next and previous buttons to work on the dynamically added articles (baring in mind they are output in the same structure)? Again, sorry for being cheeky, and thats so much for the help!

Comment: Did u comment in wrong answer? I answered u up above in our conversation if so...

Comment: How would I check for first and last hanzi, would you happen to know? Sorry to be a pain in the butt..

Thanks again.

Comment: first: `index <= 0`, last: `index >= articles.length`